# How can I write a css file from a database to a file for use with PDFKit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, heroku, stylesheet

To add a stylesheet to a pdf rendering using PDFKit, I use:

```
kit = PDFKit.new("html goes here")
kit.stylesheets << "path/to/css"
```

But I am on heroku and I need a way to be able to change the stylesheet from the web interface.  So I am creating a field to store it in the database, for example, letter.css would store the css.

How can that value be turned (I assume) into a temp file so that I can use the stylesheets method for PDFKit object?

Answer (score -1):

You can save the css contents into a file in the tmp subdirectory and include it from there - Heroku allows write access to that directory.

Comment: I know that but it also gets overwritten so that doesn't really help me to use it...nor to explain how to save it to the file....any more color?

Comment: I was thinking you would write the CSS file on demand, every time, just before adding it to the stylesheet list, so it wouldn't matter if it gets deleted between requests. The cost of writing that file is negligible compared to the cost of running PDFKit to generate the PDF file.

Comment: I see, how do I do it?  File.new?